# How to get battery status of aftermarket battery on Canon camcorder

Tags: camcorder

Is it possible to get battery status of an aftermarket battery on Canon camcorders, specifically Legria HF R26?

When I insert that battery, I get the message saying that the camcorder can't communicate with the battery pack, which is understandable since it says the same thing in the manual.

I'd just like to know if there's some kind of a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

By aftermarket do you mean generic? I.e. a battery made by a company other than Canon?

To the best of my knowledge, generic batteries won't give you a charge reading in the camera. Only original batteries will. That's just the trade off you have to live with when choosing generic batteries.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that any device you can get is not going to be able to give you charge percentage when the battery is in the camera. Doesn't the battery charger tell you the status of the charge?  I have a few cameras and they tell about it when you plug them in (they are Cannon). Maybe you can also ask in https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ and give you a solution there. Good luck.